# Image variable gets overriden even though i del it

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await, python-imaging-library, python-asyncio

So,i am working on a program involving some image manipulation,i need to do it in an asynchronous way.
So here's my relevant part of the code:

```
class ImageHandler():

    def __init__(self):

        self.fontsize=40
        self.image=Image.open("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Py-Workspace\\image-mani\\levels-card.png")
        self.font=ImageFont.truetype("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Py-Workspace\\image-mani\\big_noodle_titling.ttf",self.fontsize)


    async def add_text(self,ctx,user):

        image=self.image
        draw=ImageDraw.Draw(image)
        draw.multiline_text((10,250),f"{ctx.author.display_name}#{ctx.author.discriminator}",fill=(255,0,255),font=self.font,spacing=19)
        draw.multiline_text((10,300),f"LEVEL:{user[0]['level']}",fill=(255,0,255),font=self.font,spacing=19)
        draw.multiline_text((110,300),f"EXPEREIENCE:{user[0]['experience']}",fill=(255,0,255),font=self.font,spacing=19)
        with io.BytesIO() as output:
            image.save(output,format="PNG")
            output.seek(0)
            file=discord.File(output,'level.png')
            print(output)

        del image,draw

        return file
```

So everytime the above function is called,it's overrides on the same image,even though i'm deleting it at the end of every call and assigning it a the `self.image` instance at the start.Why does this happen.Would be nice if someone could explain

Comment: You're continually working on the same object despite using a new name for it each time. I recommend reading the following link: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: so what do i do if i wanna create a new object everytime the method gets called

Comment: `del image,draw` does absolutely nothing useful in your function, since these are local variables they would cease to exist anyway. `del` deletes *names* not objects

Answer (score 0):

When calling to the function `add_text(self,ctx,user)` the first line of the function create **another link** to the `self.image` original instance.
Therefor any changes done to the `image` variable is indeed change the original `Image`.

If order to keep the original image intact you should make a copy of it and work on it.
According to the documentation this can be done by using the [Image.copy()](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.copy) function that:

> #### Image.copy()
>
> Copies this image. Use this method if you wish to paste
>   things into an image, but still retain the original.
>
> Return type:  Image
>
> Returns:  An Image object.

While doing it there is no need to `del` the image variable any more.

So change the line:

```
image = self.image
```

With this:

```
image = self.image.copy()
```

Should resolve your issue.